# Laravel how to save comment and attaching post_id?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, crud

I'm doing my first blog with posts and comments - but i can't figure out how to save the comments and retrieve the post_id to the post_id field in comments table??

My tables look like this

comments
id | comment | post_id | user_id | updated_at | created_at

posts
id | title | content | category_id | user_id | updated_at | created_at

Any help is much appreciated:-)

Comment: You may have to share your code, what you did so far, so people here can help.

Comment: [Check on documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models).